# CMAC: Very long integer as seed for random() function

Tags: c++, random, neural-network

I've checked the documentation of stdlib and there it says that we can use an unsigned long int as seed for srand(). The problem is : I need to use a number up to 40 digits as seed. This seed is retrieved from the Association Matrix used for a multivariate CMAC problem modulation.

How can I overcome this problem?
As an example, see the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int inputVariable = getStateOfAdressedSpace();
    int generatedNumber;
    unsigned long long mySeed = getSeedFromMatrix( inputVariable );

    srandom( mySeed );
    generatedNumber = random( );
}
```

This is a very weak example, but that is because the whole code would be too big to demonstrate, just imagine that the mySeed variable would be a very long integer, that's where lies my problem. I would be very grateful if anyone shows me how to work this out, maybe even using an pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) method or something. Keep in mind that the generated number must be unique.

Comment: "I need to use a number up to 40 digits" - how can this make sense when the largest seed that can be used is smaller that that. Would it be OK to choose just the last N digits of the initial 40 digit string - such that the number is less than a `unsigned long` on your machine? That would be my approach... because the system cannot distinguish between all possible 40 digits seeds you throw at it, there must be a point where they "collide". Even a `long long` is less than 40 digits, isn't it?

Comment: Yes Floris, long long is indeed less than 40 digits, it's 20 digits actually (I guess), however I really need these 40 digits to represent an state of my problem. These digits are obtained from a Matrix, and if I change 1 digit, or add less than the necessary, this completely changes the state represented by those number, and the CMAC modulation wouldn't work properly.

Comment: "the generated number must be unique" - unique among which other numbers? You have 10^40 possible seeds, and 100 possible random numbers generated by `random( )%100`. What uniqueness are you talking about?

Comment: Could you hash the 40 digits and use that result?

Comment: Do you actually have 1E40 different states? That is almost inconceivable - especially if these states are _practically_ distinct, rather than _measurably_. Just think - there are some 6 or 7 billion (1E9) humans on the planet; maybe 9 million different species of "life forms"; can you reduce the "number of states" in some way? I can't believe you use all 1E40 possible values...

Comment: Igor Tandetnik, I've fixed the example I gave, that wasn't making any sense, in fact it's something about 10^40 different states (or different numbers).
Carey Gregory, That would depend... The number could be hashed, but the final number would have to be unique. For example, if I get the results of the numbers generated by the hashed seed and combine them in sum, I would likely have two, actually very likely more than two, equals numbers.

Comment: Don't use `srand`, it's completely unsuitable. Look at `std::random`, or failing that `boost::random`. Both support seeding with large amounts of data, and generators that can make use of it (e.g. mersenne twister). But you will need to think about exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Floris, it is pretty easy to have that number of states in a problem. Imagine the number of possibilities you can analyse in a soccer game, for example: Position of the ball, Position of the player with the ball, Position of each players, pass direction, pass speed, wind velocity, wind direction, players fatigue... Well, basically, there's an infinite possibilities of states, my problem is very complex, even more complex than a soccer game, that's why I have to deal with so many states.

Comment: I see what you mean - although you will not ever "visit" all 10^40 states, they are "possible". Why does each state need a unique (distinct) random number seed? Isn't the whole point of random numbers that they are random? If you already know "it is different from all the others", are you still truly random?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve something that will be "indistinguishable from random", and that uses all digits of an arbitrary length seed, would be the following (untested - this is just to show the principle):

```
char* mySeed = "123454321543212345678908765434234576897654267349587623459872039487102367529364520";
char bitOfString[6];
int ii;
long int randomNumber=0;
for(ii=0; ii<strlen(mySeed)-5; ii+=5) {
  strncpy(bitOfString, mySeed+ii, 5);
  bitOfString[5]='\0';
  srandom(atoi(bitOfString));
  randomNumber += random();
}
randomNumber = randomNumber % RAND_MAX;
```

This generates random numbers based on "something that is small enough to be a seed" (I used the number `5` for string length but you could pick another number; depends on the size of `int` on your machine).  You could make it "more random" by not picking just the first random number generated in each loop, but the Nth (so that swapping around blocks of digits would not produce the same result).

Bottom line is - you generate a different random sequence. It is a mathematical impossibility that each of 10<sup>40</sup> seeds will give a different random number - this method should map a seed of "arbitrary size" to a uniformly distributed number in the range of the random number generator.

Note that I used `long int` for `randomNumber` although `random()` produces an `int` random. This allows the summation of multiple random numbers without fear of overflow - and the final modulo division ensures that the number you end up with will be (approximately) uniformly distributed (especially if you ended up making a large number of calls to `random()` ).

Looking forward to your thoughts on this.